# Perl regular expression: syntax help needed

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, how do I combine these 2 statements in one line?

```
$str=~ s/=>/:/g;
$str=~ s/\$VAR1 = {//g;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str =~ s/(=>|\$VAR = {)/$1 eq '=>' && ':'/ge;
```

Though, really, you're better off leaving the code as it is unless you have some really, really compelling reason for combining the statements.

Comment: wow where did you learn this technique? any tips for learning reg expression?

Comment: I guess it's that really advanced technique called "Reading the Fine Manual" :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simply — just change the "`;`" to "`,`" — but why? Combining two statements is not a goal, it's a means. If you told us what your goal, you could give you a better answer.

```
$str=~ s/=>/:/g, $str=~ s/\$VAR1 = {//g;
```

Other ways:

```
do { $str=~ s/=>/:/g; $str=~ s/\$VAR1 = {//g; };

s/=>/:/g, s/\$VAR1 = {//g for $str;

$str = $str =~ s/=>/:/gr =~ s/\$VAR1 = {//gr;   # 5.14+ required.
```